# tableView.reloadData() causing a crash of the app

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, ios8

In the Swift app, I present an addition view to add an element to the CoreData database. If I call tableview.reloadData(), the app crashes on the + button on the main screen. If I omit the reload data then the add view is presented and the data is added to the CoreData file.

the main view, from configureCell down:

```
func configureCell(cell: TransectTableViewCell, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {

    let transectEntry = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Transects

    cell.transectNameLabel.text = transectEntry.transectName
    cell.transectNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.transectNameLabel.shadowColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.transectNameLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let countEntry = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Transects
        coreDataStack.context.deleteObject(countEntry)
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> CGFloat {
        return 50;
}

func didFinishViewController(viewController: AddTransectViewController, didSave: Bool) {

    if didSave {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let context = viewController.context
        self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "addTransectSegue" {

        let newTransectViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddTransectViewController
        let transectEntryEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Transects", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
        let newTransectEntry = Transects(entity: transectEntryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)

        newTransectViewController.transectNewEntry = newTransectEntry
        newTransectViewController.context = newTransectEntry.managedObjectContext
        newTransectViewController.delegate = self
    }

    if segue.identifier == "transectTasksSegue" {

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let transectSelected = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Transects

        let tasksViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TransectTasksViewController
        tasksViewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack

        tasksViewController.selectedTransect = transectSelected

    }
}


func controllerDidChangeContent(controller:
    NSFetchedResultsController) {
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The addition view is:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

protocol TransectDelegate {

    func didFinishViewController(ViewController:AddTransectViewController, didSave:Bool)
}

class AddTransectViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var transectNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var altitudeTextField: UITextField!

    var transectNewEntry: Transects!

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var delegate:TransectDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func updateTransectEntry() {

        if let entry = transectNewEntry {

            entry.transectName = transectNameTextField.text
            entry.latitude = latitudeTextField.text
            entry.longitude = longitudeTextField.text
            entry.altitude = altitudeTextField.text
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.didFinishViewController(self, didSave: false)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        updateTransectEntry()
        delegate?.didFinishViewController(self, didSave: true)
    }

}
```

I am missing something, but cannot see what. Ideas would be welcome.

The app hangs up on cell.transectNameLabel.text = transectEntry.transectName

with: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

My real confusion is that this works perfectly:

```
 import UIKit
```

import CoreData

class PlantSpeciesViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, PlantSpeciesDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!

var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!
lazy var fetchedResultController:
NSFetchedResultsController = self.plantSpeciesFetchedResultsController()

var plantSpecies: PlantSpecies!

var selectedFamily: PlantFamily!

var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

var plantFamilyName: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage (named: "Monitor backdrop.png")!)

    self.title = plantFamilyName
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func plantSpeciesFetchedResultsController()
    ->NSFetchedResultsController {

        fetchedResultController =
            NSFetchedResultsController(
                fetchRequest: plantSpeciesFetchRequest(),
                managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context,
                sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                cacheName: nil)

        fetchedResultController.delegate = self

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if (!fetchedResultController.performFetch(&error)){
            println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            abort()
        }

        return fetchedResultController
}

func plantSpeciesFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PlantSpecies")
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "familyName == %@", selectedFamily)

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "plantSpecies", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    //var error: NSError?

    return fetchRequest
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return fetchedResultController.sections!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return fetchedResultController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("plantSpeciesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlantSpeciesTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: PlantSpeciesTableViewCell, indexPath:NSIndexPath) {

    let plantEntry = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PlantSpecies

    cell.speciesNameLabel.text = plantEntry.plantSpecies
    cell.speciesNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.speciesNameLabel.shadowColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.speciesNameLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)

    cell.speciesImageView.image = UIImage (data: plantEntry.plantImage)
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let countEntry = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PlantFamily
        coreDataStack.context.deleteObject(countEntry)
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> CGFloat {
        return 90;
}

func didFinishViewController(viewController: AddPlantSpeciesViewController, didSave: Bool) {

    if didSave {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let context = viewController.context
        self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "addSpeciesSegue" {

        let newPlantViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddPlantSpeciesViewController
        let plantEntryEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("PlantSpecies", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)
        let newSpeciesEntry = PlantSpecies(entity: plantEntryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)

        newPlantViewController.selectedFamily = selectedFamily

        newPlantViewController.plantNameEntry = newSpeciesEntry
        newPlantViewController.context = newSpeciesEntry.managedObjectContext
        newPlantViewController.delegate = self
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller:
    NSFetchedResultsController) {

        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

coupled with:

import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

protocol PlantSpeciesDelegate {

```
func didFinishViewController(ViewController:AddPlantSpeciesViewController, didSave:Bool)
```

}

class AddPlantSpeciesViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var plantNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var plantImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet weak var imageFromFileButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var imageFromCameraButton: UIButton!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

var plantNameEntry: PlantSpecies!
var selectedFamily: PlantFamily!

var passedPlantFamily: String!

var newPlantName: String!
var newImageData: NSData!

var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
var delegate:PlantSpeciesDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    plantImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder image.jpg")

    imagePicker.delegate = self

}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func imageSourceSwitch(sender: AnyObject) {

    if imageSwitch.on == true
    {
        self.imageFromFileButton.enabled = true
        self.imageFromCameraButton.enabled = false
    }

    else
    {
        self.imageFromCameraButton.enabled = true
        self.imageFromFileButton.enabled = false
    }
}


@IBAction func imageFromFile(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func imageFromCamera(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.plantImageView.image = image
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func getPlantName() {

    newPlantName = plantNameTextField.text
    plantNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func updateSpeciesEntry() {

    if let entry = plantNameEntry {

        entry.plantSpecies = newPlantName
        entry.plantImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(plantImageView.image, 1.0)
        entry.familyName = selectedFamily
    }
}

@IBAction func cancelButtonWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.didFinishViewController(self, didSave: false)
}


@IBAction func saveButtonWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    updateSpeciesEntry()
    delegate?.didFinishViewController(self, didSave: true)
}
```

}
  So, what is the difference?

Comment: could you please post the crash log?

Comment: Need more info. What is the crash error? Where?

Comment: Agree, make sure your error breakpoint is enabled to provide us more information.

Answer (score 4):

This happen to me too, fixed it with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

instead of just tableView.reloadData()
, cause it seems that it was being called from wrong thread.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the crash is most likely that the table cannot load the data, for example a value does not exist and is being force unwrapped. The crash only happens, therefore, when you try to collect the data. Check through all the values to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand on GJZ answer & what brought me here. I have UITableViewCells that have a textfield. I attempted to get values the user entered from the field.

```
let companyNameCell:  TextEntryCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! TextEntryCell
```

what I realized is that when I dynamically hide and showed rows by changing the cell heights using the tableview.reloadrows method, the app would crash if it attempted to read a cell the user could not see on their screen. that is because the cells I think were deallocated.